# jquery radio button not returning right value

Tags: jquery, radio-button, show-hide

This is a noob question. I have searched around the Radio Button jquery stuff and i get confused cause there is a lot of dynamic radio buttons and such. Anyway, I am trying to do a simple Show/Hide div thingie.

but for some reason my code always returns the same value of "3" for the radio button regardless of what is selected.

So here is my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="testjq.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="radios">


    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radBut" checked="checked" value="1">
    1
  <br>

    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radBut" value="2">
    2
  <br>

    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radBut" value="3">
    3<br>

    <span id="VAL">value is = </span>
  <br>

</div>
<div id="story1">
Story 1
</div>
<div id="story2" style="display:none">
Story 2
</div>
<div id="story3" style="display:none"> 
Story 3
</div>
```

and here is the jQuery/java which is in the testjq.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testVar = 1;
        $('input:radio[name=radBut]:checked').val(); {
            var testVar = $(this).val();
        }
        if (testVar = 3){
            $("#story3").show();
            $("#story2").show();
            $("#story1").show();
            }
        else if (testVar = 2){
            $("#story3").hide();
            $("#story2").show();
            $("#story1").show();
            }
        else {
            $("#story3").hide();
            $("#story2").hide();
            $("#story1").show();
        }
        $('#VAL').append(testVar);

});
```

any suggestions as to what i got wrong?

Comment: if only everyone saw Doris's crockford's video. they'd know abt `===`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with what other ppl said, I made this a lil better. Cleaner atleast.

First I took your code where you check the `testVar` and put it in a function :

```
function testWithVar(testVar) {
    //store all the story divs in a variable
    var stories = $('[id^="story"]')
    //hide all the variables and show the variables according to testVar
    stories.hide().filter(':lt(' + testVar + ')').show();
    //append the value
    $('#VAL').html("value is = " + testVar);
}
```

So in `ready`, you'd call it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    testWithVar(1);
});
```

And, if you want to change the of `testVar` everytime you choose a value in the radio group, make a `change` event which will call `testWithVar` function in `ready` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    testWithVar(1);
    $('input:radio[name=radBut]').change(function () {
        testWithVar(this.value);
    });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/CQDyz/

References :

- [starts with selector](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=starts%20with%20in%20jquery&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/&ei=OpXIUf-NC4n_rAeH-YHIBg&usg=AFQjCNFLvKsFLaadTmLDnPiJ5xOHtQb-8g&sig2=ByevR2c1qf-Gr85Fr50VNw&bvm=bv.48293060,d.bmk)
- [filter method](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=filter%20in%20jquery&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/filter/&ei=r5XIUcXeH4-3rAfu2oFo&usg=AFQjCNGIjOndwopfFySn6E1gc8znkMPSPw&sig2=HQg7ShgJPW8CWS9XhqiE6w&bvm=bv.48293060,d.bmk)
- [lesser than selector (lt)](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

Comment: I am in the process of trying to understand your code. right now its a bit fuzzy, but your comments in the code are helping greatly. (mostly its fuzzy cause my understanding is low) This actually has the functionality i was looking for. Once i have wrapped my head around this it will aid me greatly. I really appreciate your help on this :)

Comment: I've added some references at the bottom to make you understand more :-)

Comment: @SpikeyTheDesigner if u think one of these answers have helped u, pls mark it as the right answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

This chunk right here:

```
$('input:radio[name=radBut]:checked').val(); {
        var testVar = $(this).val();
}
```

Should be:

```
testVar = $('input:radio[name=radBut]:checked').val();
```

There is no need to re-declare this variable since it is already declared.

Also, all of your `if` conditions only have one `=`, they need TWO `==`

Answer (score 3):

```
if (testVar = 3){
```

That says, essentially, "set `testVar` to `3` then return `true`" because `=` is the assignment operator. You want the equality operator `==`:

```
if (testVar == 3){
```

Similarly, look at

```
else if (testVar = 2){
```

This needs the same change to `==`.

Also, look at this:

```
$('input:radio[name=radBut]:checked').val(); {
    var testVar = $(this).val();
}
```

This is valid JS, but it doesn't do what you think. It says "get the value of the checked box, then ignore it, then set `testVar` to the `value` of `document`." This isn't what you mean. Do this:

```
vat testVar = $('input[name=radBut]:checked').val();
```

Note that the `:radio` selector is unnecessary and will slow the selection down significantly.

Comment: Your plain language explanation of what is happening aided in my understanding. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

**testVar** will always be what you are equating it to. To make a comparison, you have to use the '==' sign. Using '=' means you are assigning  value to the variable.

You can also use '===' which is more secured.